# Regex : advanced removing single line PHP comments

Tags: php, regex, visual-studio

I'd like to remove all single line comments in some PHP code like this one using Visual Basic :

```
<?php
some code
// "(\/\/[^;)]*)(?=\?\>)"         <-- NOT REMOVED
/* a first comment */
/* a second comment with some // inside
// a single line ; comment inside         <-- NOT REMOVED
// a comment with a ; website http://www.google.com         <-- NOT REMOVED
a third comment
*/
/* a fourth comment with some // inside */
/* a fifth comment with some ftp://ftp.google;com//onefolder inside */
some code
if {// a comment         <-- NOT REMOVED
    doit();
} /* another comment */
some more code// a comment         <-- NOT REMOVED
some more code2// a comment         <-- NOT REMOVED
?>
<?php  // a comment with a website http://www.google.com ?>
<?php and some more code // and a comment ?>
<?php var = 'http://www.google;com'; // and a comment ?>
<?php var = 'https://www.google;com'; // and a comment ?>
<?php var = 'ftp://www.google;com'; // and a comment ?>
<?php var = 'ftp://www.google;com'; // a comment with a website http://www.google.com ?>
<?php var = 'ftp://www.google;com'; // a comment ?         <-- NOT REMOVED
?>
```

I'm using for the moment the `"(\/\/[^;)]*)(?=\?\>)"` pattern, that works for part, but I still have remaining lines (see `<-- NOT REMOVED` tags). I don't succeed in telling the regex to delete until it finds a `?>` sequence, **if it is there** before the end of line...

Can you help me to improve this regex ?

So it gives this (or something near according to the remaining \n and multiples spaces left after the comments cleaning, that I can remove in a next clean) :

```
<?php
some code  

/* a first comment */
/* a second comment with some // inside <-- END CAN BE REMOVED, NO PROBLEM
  

a third comment
*/
/* a fourth comment with some // inside */ <-- CAN BE REMOVED IF THE ENDING */ IS KEPT
/* a fifth comment with some ftp://ftp.google;com//onefolder inside */
some code
if {
    doit();
} /* another comment */
some more code
some more code2
?>
<?php ?>
<?php and some more code ?>
<?php var = 'http://www.google;com'; ?>
<?php var = 'https://www.google;com'; ?>
<?php var = 'ftp://www.google;com'; ?>
<?php var = 'ftp://www.google;com'; ?>
<?php var = 'ftp://www.google;com'; 
?>
```

NOTE : I have no problem doing this in multiple passes if this can lead to an easier-to-read code.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense what you're trying to do. This part `[^;)]*` is especially confusing.  What does all the `<-- NOT REMOVED` annotations mean ? Are you trying to exclude/include  `<?php  ?>` from comment processing ? Just a side fyi here, Weather inside a code block or outside, there is a hierarchy in the search for comment syntax. Specifically every pair of quotes have to be parsed out first since they _hide_ comment syntax. After that each character that does not initiate a comment must be written back along with quoted text. There is no shortcuts !

Comment: @sln:Question edited to clarify the <-- NOT REMOVED tags. I just want to remove what are single line comments, and keep everything else. Including <?php ?> tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sample input was extended:

`*(?<!:)//(?:.*?)(?= ?\*\/| ?\?>|$)`

Basically, it comes down to how you want to guard against urls (which contain `//`) -- I'll "lookbehind" for a `:` before a `//`.  You may want to clear any lingering `<?php ?>` lines as a subsequent (non-regex) replacement.

This pattern consumes zero or more spaces before the comment starts, but leaves a potential space before `*/`, `?>`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's a huge improvement. But it has a flaw : if the comment is stuck to the end of the code, it is ignored, for example if the space before the comment is removed (ex: 'if {// a comment') ou ('some more code// a comment'). I edit the question accordingly. Could you improve that ?

Comment: The cold, hard truth about this task is that there will always be edge cases that a regex pattern will not handle properly.  Regex is not a code parsing tool.  There can very easily be `//` substrings legitmately found inside of a string in the code.  I would not recommend blindly doing a project-wide bulk replacement using regex.  It will help speed up your task to employ this regex , but I recommend that you confirm the accuracy of the match with a human eye so that you don't corrupt your scripts.

Answer (score -1):

How about:
https://regex101.com/r/Pua5qG/latest

```
(?x)                        # freespacing
(                           # never match // in..
['"].*\/\/.*['"]            # ... a strings
|
\/\*.*?\*\/                 # .. a comment
)
(*SKIP)(*FAIL)              # if you do-skip that match
|
(?P<commented_code>\/\/.+?) # capture comments
(?P<end>\?>$)?              # omit ?> at end of line
$
```

and replace with `${end}` in consequence only throwing away comments

Comment: Does Visual Studio permit `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`?  I don't know because I don't use it.  I know that PHPStorm doesn't allow it -- just says "bad pattern".   ... can't use `\K` either.

Comment: I might be completely wrong, but I would think that VSC is just a text editor, so it should not matter for the regex. Since PHP uses PCRE2, which in turn knows `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` I think it would work.

Comment: I have just tested in Visual Studio and `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` is not supported (neither is `\K`).  The IDE is simply using a different engine that PHP uses.